# Writing to a Running Jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to create a Jar file that contains data **inside the Jar** that persists between executions of the program. I know there are other ways to save data, but I'm going for a fully self-contained Jar file.

I have something that seems to work, and I'd like feedback on any holes you see in my approach, as something *feels* hackish about it. What I'm doing is this:

- The Jar contains a file, saves.txt. This file contains a single digit: at the beginning, it's 1.
- When the Jar is run, it reads this file (using getResourceAsStream) and displays that number to the user.
- I then extract the whole jar to a temporary directory using the ZipFile API.
- Now that saves.txt is a File (not a resource), I increment the number and overwrite the file in the temp directory.
- Then I use the JarOutputStream to rezip the contents of the temporary directory (including the updated saves.txt file) **back into the same jar**.
- Finally, I delete the temporary directory and the program exits. When the user runs the jar again, the saves.txt file has been updated.

I'm doing all this rigmarole to get around this bug, where you can't just update a single file inside a jar: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4129445

And I'm not using the jar -u command because I don't want to require end users have the JDK.

I can see a few problems with this, but none of them are deal-breakers for me:

- This won't work with signed jars. That's not a problem for me, since these jars won't be signed anyway.
- This won't work if the jar is in a directory without write privileges. I can warn the user about that.
- This won't work if the jar is open in an archive explorer (like 7zip) while the program is run. I can get around this by simply showing the user a message asking them to close it.
- This makes deploying a new version of the jar annoying, as the saves are inside the jar. The user will either have to somehow load the data from the old jar, or start clean. I'm okay with that too.

So, my question is: **does any of the above seem particularly horrible?** And if so, why?

Edit: I should note that I'm not really asking about whether the approach is standard or confusing, I'm asking about **the code**. Is there any reason **the code** won't work?

The "rewriting the contents of the jar while the jar is being run" step is the one that makes me the most nervous, but I can't find any documentation that says you can't, or even shouldn't, do this. If I did this in the middle of the program, then maybe bad things would happen, but this will only happen at the very end of the program. Overwriting the jar is the very last line of the program.

And most importantly of all, this all seems to work! I've tested this on Windows 7, Windows 8, and Mac. So if anybody knows of any documentation, or can think of a corner case where this code won't work, I'd definitely appreciate it.

Here is an MCVE showing all of the above. For this to work, you have to compile this class into a runnable jar file along with a saves.txt file that contains a single digit.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JarTest {

    static List<File> extractedFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    public static void unzipWholeJar() throws IOException{

        File jarFile = new File(JarTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        ZipFile jarZipFile = new ZipFile(jarFile);

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entities = jarZipFile.entries();

        while (entities.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry)entities.nextElement();

            if(!entry.isDirectory()){

                InputStream in = jarZipFile.getInputStream(jarZipFile.getEntry(entry.getName()));

                File file = new File("extracted/" + entry.getName());

                extractedFiles.add(file);

                File parent = new File(file.getParent());
                parent.mkdirs();

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                int bufferSize;
                while ((bufferSize = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        }

        jarZipFile.close();
    }

    public static void rezipExtractedFiles() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        File jarFile = new File(JarTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jarFile)));

        for(File f : extractedFiles){
            String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
            String fileInJar = absPath.substring(absPath.indexOf("extracted") + 10);
            addFile(jos, fileInJar, f);
        }

        jos.close();
    }

    public static void addFile(JarOutputStream jos, String fileInJar, File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

        jos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileInJar));

        int bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        while ((bufferSize = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            jos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        in.close();
        jos.closeEntry();

    }

    public static void updateSavesFile(int newX) throws IOException{
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("extracted/saves.txt"));
        writer.write(String.valueOf(newX));
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void deleteExtracted(File f){
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            for (File c : f.listFiles())
                deleteExtracted(c);
        }
        f.delete();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException{

        //read saves file in
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JarTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("saves.txt")));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(line);
        br.close();

        //show the message
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Times opened: " + x);

        //unzip the whole jar
        //this will fail if the jar is in a folder without write privileges
        //but I can catch that and warn the user
        unzipWholeJar();

        //update the unzipped saves file
        updateSavesFile(x+1);

        //put the files back into the jar
        //this will fail if the jar is open in an archive explorer
        //but I can catch that and warn the user
        rezipExtractedFiles();

        //delete what we extracted
        deleteExtracted(new File("extracted"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title is really Horrible. Please consider changing it.

Comment: Saving data back into the JAR file sounds weird. A JAR is comparable to an .exe file (on Windows). No program saves data inside its own .exe file. Why not just save the data in a separate file?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You're no fun. Title changed.

Comment: Adding to what @Jesper said, users assume that the program doesn't contain the data, so what stops the user from making a copy of the .jar, then running a version with old data and getting really confused?

Comment: I feel this might be better asked on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since this code works but needs to be reviewed.

Comment: @Jesper I agree it seems weird. The question is **why**. I am aware of the alternatives, but I'm trying to create an entirely self-contained solution. The idea is that you can persists data between runs without worrying about where that data is. This is part of a larger program that handles the automatic extraction of native library files.

Comment: @mellamokb I agree. I listed that as a downside. But that's not a *programmatic* reason not to do it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I considered that, but I don't know that this code will work in every case. I'm assuming I'm missing something from the API or JLS somewhere. If it really bothers people I can delete and repost.

Comment: Typically programs save their data in well-established common locations like %APPDATA% or ProgramData on Windows.  The user doesn't have to know anything about where the data is saved (or care), and you manage the data entirely as the programmer.  What is wrong with this standard solution for your use case?

Comment: @mellamokb Nothing is really wrong with that approach, this is just a different approach. This is part of a toolset designed for novice Processing developers, which currently allows them to package their programs (which require native libraries) as a runnable jar. This addition would allow them to persist data between runs, since Processing requires external files.

Answer (score 3):

**Concept**:

It is kind of awful.

- It is wasteful, compared to using configuration files outside of the jar.
- It doesn't *really* add value. Users usually don't care where the configuration files live.
- It saves state *in* the program. Why is this bad? Because they're not seperated, users cannot easily transfer the configuration without copying the whole program, or share the program without sharing their configuration.
- If you can read and rewrite the jar, you can also write configuration files to the same directory. Usually.
- Assuming it does work flawlessly, it complicates your code, possibly unnecessarily.
- If it doesn't work, your users might be left with a broken executable. Not a good user experience.

You don't need to put it into the same jar. Being able to export a snapshot of the jar, bundled with the configuration into the program, *might* be a feature, but it likely isn't valuable enough to have it by default.

**Implementation**:

What happens when the host OS runs out of resources? File descriptors, space...
You might get a `NullPointerException` in `java.io.File.<init>`, but what state did you leave on the hard-drive? Can your program handle existing files? All this is unneeded complexity, that you *could* avoid by using files outside of the jar.

The writing could fail at any moment, due to external causes. And since you don't use finally blocks to close your streams, I'm not sure if the changes will be flushed.

**Conclusion**:

Facing the persistence problem you're having with Processing, this is a clever hack, but still a hack. It will blow up, sometime, for someone. If you can avoid, do it. On the other hand, I might misunderstand the problem with Processing, so there might be solution that is more appropriate.

Comment: I am the author of a tool that handles automatic self-extraction of native library files in Java and Processing. Processing requires data be saved as an external File, but there isn't a built-in way to persist that data. This is a theoretical solution to that problem. All of your concerns seem to be about *the idea itself* rather than the programming behind it though.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: You've demonstrated that it works.  If you don't want any comments on the potential pitfalls of the idea, what is the point of your question?

Comment: Yes, from reading the question and `does any of the above seem particularly horrible?`, I assumed you requested critic on the approach.

Comment: Fair enough. Question updated to specify that I'm asking about code.

Comment: Your edited answer is closer to what I'm looking for, thanks. The problem you mentioned with the OS would seem to exist with *any* solution that writes to the harddrive though. I agree that it seems like a hack, the question is: can anybody out there think of when that "sometime" is?

Comment: I suppose when you enter FUSE filesystems on Linux, things get nasty. Not saying you *have to* support these, but basically, anything that doesn't fulfill your assumptions might blow up. What if the filesystem uses paths that are neither seperated by `/`, nor by \? Use [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) to adapt to this. But there will be things which you likely won't think of before some trips over them.

Answer (score 1):

Really a strange solution. Why do not use a file outside the .jar to store the data?.

Some problems i see on your solution:

- Complexity. Its not clear why its the advantage of all this extra complexity vs store the data in a file.
- Versioning: When you need to distribute a new version of your program to your clients in a .jar you are overriding the data inside the .jar!. You need to think in a complex program update mechanism, again unjustified complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is kind of awful.

You can use a zip file system for URLs "jar:file:/...". Then you would simply to manipulate a single "File" inside the zip (jar).

I am not sure, one may change the jar one is running. On Linux probably yes.

```
Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
// zipProperties.put("create", "true");
zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarUri, zipProperties)) {
    Path dataPath = zipFS.getPath("/data/file.txt");
    ...
    Files.copy(inputStream, dataPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, and I wonder how it interacts with the bug I listed above preventing exactly that kind of thing. Can you post the code you would use to update a single jar entry file?

Comment: Did just add some code. Your analysis is just fine. This just goes a bit faster - when working without the caveats you mention. And it is easier code. There is much to be said to hold the data in `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.myapp/file.txt"`.